# How do you select rows from an excel spreadsheet based off of a column value and insert it into dataGridViews?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am creating a winform that has has a tab control with three tabs which each contain their own dataGridViews. I have an excel spreadsheet that contains data for all three tables. These all have the same headers (Name, Type, Date, Cost). There are three different categories of `type`, these being hire, relocate, and service. I would like to create a method that inserts data from the file to the three dataGridViews based on some sort of where clause that separates them based off their type.

Here is what I have so far. Ive added some comments to help aid my question:

```
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\temp\Activity.csv"))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + file);
        string[] data;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            data = lines[i].ToString().Split(',');

            string[] row = new string[data.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = data[j].Trim();
            }
            
            //dgv1 is the dataGridView for hire
            form.dgv1.Rows.Add(row); //I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = hire

            //dgv2 is the dataGridView for service
            form.dgv2.Rows.Add(row);//I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = service

            //dgv3 is the dataGridView for relocate
            form.dgv3.Rows.Add(row);//I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = relocate
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of what the file looks like:
| Name  | Type     | Date       | Cost |
| ----- | -------- | ---------- | ---- |
| Jack  | service  | 18/03/2021 | 499  |
| John  | hire     | 23/02/2021 | 199  |
| Steve | hire     | 01/11/2020 | 249  |
| Suzie | relocate | 21/03/2021 | 44   |

It would do something like this:

```
            if (Type = hire)
            {
                dgv1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            if (Type = service) {
                dgv2.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            if (Type = relocate)
            {
                dgv3.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

But I'm not sure how to code this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what of your above code is working, but if your `row` variable is getting populated with the correct values from your columns, then you should be able to just check the value of the second item in your `row` array to get the type. The second item in your `row` array should correspond to the type.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\temp\Activity.csv"))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + file);
    string[] data;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        data = lines[i].ToString().Split(',');

        string[] row = new string[data.Length];

        for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
        {
            row[j] = data[j].Trim();
        }

        //dgv1 is the dataGridView for hire
        if (row[1] == "hire")
        {
            form.dgv1.Rows.Add(row); //I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = hire
        }
        //dgv2 is the dataGridView for service
        else if (row[1] == "service")
        {
            form.dgv2.Rows.Add(row);//I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = service
        }
        //dgv3 is the dataGridView for relocate
        else if (row[1] == "relocate")
        {
            form.dgv3.Rows.Add(row);//I want to add the excel row to this datagrid if the 'type' column = relocate
        }
    }
}
```